# Can men wear Silk EyeMask while sleeping?

Tags: fiqh, clothing

I recently ordered an eye mask, which has 100% silk on it's underside. I know that wearing silk is haram for men, but does an eye mask come under clothing and the amount of fabric is also very less ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "eye masks" aka blindfolds are considered garments that are worn. As per [Bukhari hadith 5837](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/54), silk is prohibited for males in the form of wearing it and in the form of sleeping on it. In your case, it's a little bit of both. Therefore, men should refrain from wearing this item. Gift it to a female relative and find another eye mask that isn't made from 100% pure silk.